# Why does poll indicate a kqueue watching a single empty Mach port set is readable?

Tags: macos, polling, kqueue, mach

I've got a kqueue watching a single item: an empty Mach port set. `kevent64` says there are no events available, and `select` indicates the kqueue is not ready for reading. But `poll` says the kqueue *is* readable! - though this doesn't appear to be the case when subsequently calling `kevent64` to read the supposedly ready event(s).

The code I'm using is below. You can build it with something like `gcc -Wall -std=c99 -o test test.c`, and then run it with `./test` or whatever. It prints out return values from `kevent64` (count of events actually retrieved after an attempt was made to read 1 without waiting), `select` (count of file descriptors ready for reading after polling), and `poll` (count of file descriptors ready for reading after polling).

The output I'd expect would be something like this, indicating that `kevent64`, `select` and `poll` all agree that the kqueue is empty.

```
$ ./kqueue_poll_machport
kevent64: 0
select: 0
poll: 0 (revents: 0)
kevent64: 0
```

But what I actually get is this, showing that `kevent64` and `select` say one thing, and `poll` another - and, furthermore, that even after `poll` has indicated the kqueue is readable, `kevent64` still says there is no event to be read (this being the reason for the second `kevent64` call).

```
$ ./kqueue_poll_machport
kevent64: 0
select: 0
poll: 1 (revents: 1)
kevent64: 0
```

(The 1 value for `revents` is `POLLIN`, indicating, supposedly, that data may be read without blocking. The result is the same if I specify `POLLRDNORM` and `POLLRDBAND` independently.)

Why the discrepancy?

My test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <mach/mach.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/event.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <poll.h>

int main(void) {
    kern_return_t kr;
    int rc;

    int kq=kqueue();
    assert(kq!=-1);

    mach_port_name_t port_set;
    kr=mach_port_allocate(mach_task_self(),MACH_PORT_RIGHT_PORT_SET,&port_set);
    assert(kr==KERN_SUCCESS);

    {
        const struct kevent64_s events[]={
            {
                .flags=EV_ADD|EV_ENABLE,
                .filter=EVFILT_MACHPORT,
                .ident=port_set,
            },
        };

        rc=kevent64(kq,events,sizeof events/sizeof events[0],NULL,0,0,NULL);
        assert(rc==0);
    }

    /* Events available? */
    {
        const struct timespec NO_TIMEOUT={0,0};
        struct kevent64_s event;
        rc=kevent64(kq,NULL,0,&event,1,0,&NO_TIMEOUT);
        printf("kevent64: %d\n",rc);
    }

    /* Test readability with select. */
    {
        const struct timeval NO_TIMEOUT={0,0};
        fd_set rd;
        FD_ZERO(&rd);
        FD_SET(kq,&rd);
        rc=select(kq+1,&rd,NULL,NULL,&NO_TIMEOUT);
        printf("select: %d\n",rc);
    }

    /* Test readibility with poll. */
    {
        struct pollfd fds[]={
            {
                .fd=kq,
                .events=POLLIN,
            },
        };
        rc=poll(fds,sizeof fds/sizeof fds[0],0);
        printf("poll: %d (revents: %d)\n",rc,fds[0].revents);
    }

    /* Events available? */
    {
        const struct timespec NO_TIMEOUT={0,0};
        struct kevent64_s event;
        rc=kevent64(kq,NULL,0,&event,1,0,&NO_TIMEOUT);
        printf("kevent64: %d\n",rc);
    }
}
```